# Finding Fourier coefficients of functions that are defined as integrals with known Fourier coefficients?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

Given a continuous periodic function f, with a period of  $2\pi$, and Fourier coefficients that are $\hat f(n) = \frac{1}{1+n^2}$ , what are the Fourier coefficients of $g(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt $?

So far I've plugged $f(x) = S_nf$ into the definition of the Fourier coefficients of g(x), but I'm a little bit confused and could use some help.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus $g'(x)=f(x)$. Then, integrating by parts, we get
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}g(x)\,e^{inx}\,dx&=g(x)\,\frac{e^{inx}}{i\,n}\Bigr|_0^{2\pi}-\frac{1}{i\,n}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\,e^{inx}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{i\,n}\Bigr(\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\,dx-\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\,e^{inx}\,dx\Bigr).
\end{align}
$$

Observe that $g$ is periodic of period $2\,\pi$ if and only if $\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\,dx=0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Wow, you read my mind!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The fact that g is periodic is given in the question, but I mistakenly left it out of the question.